# What is the nature of a compiled script in JSR-223 context

Tags: java, javax.script

I couldn't find any clear answer.
Is the script translated to ByteCode ? to a script specific pseudo-code ?

When i use a compiled nashorn script, is it simply compiled because the JIT compiler did its job on a java translation of the script 
OR 
because a specific parsed version of the script has been prepared for a nashorn kind of interpreting VM (kind of smallTalk option) ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "nature" of a compiled script is entirely up to the script engine, e.g.

- The raw script itself, if the script language doesn't have a compiled version
- A parsed intermediate object, e.g. an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for an expression
- Internal object structures for evaluating the script, e.g. what a regular expression compiles to
- Byte code
- ...

The reason you can't find a clear answer, is that there is no clear answer. Every script engine will do its own thing.